# Wide listings in twoside book

Tags: listings, double-sided

On this MWE, I'm trying to make listings environment larger than textwidth by setting `linewidth = \textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth`. But, the result is not what I want. On page 2, listings environment should be started at left margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[includeall]{geometry}

\usepackage{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\lstlen
\setlength{\lstlen}{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}

\lstset{%
    basicstyle          = \ttfamily\small,
    language            = c,
    columns             = fullflexible,
    flexiblecolumns     = false,
    emptylines          = *1,
    tabsize             = 4,
    breaklines          = true,
    showstringspaces    = false,
    linewidth           = \lstlen,
    frame               = single,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cairo.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.1415927
#endif

#define GR(X,Y) (d[(*s)*(Y)+bpp*(X)+((2)%bpp)])
#define GG(X,Y) (d[(*s)*(Y)+bpp*(X)+((1)%bpp)])
#define GB(X,Y) (d[(*s)*(Y)+bpp*(X)+((0)%bpp)])
#define SR(X,Y) (ht[4*tw*((Y)%th)+4*((X)%tw)+2])
#define SG(X,Y) (ht[4*tw*((Y)%th)+4*((X)%tw)+1])
#define SB(X,Y) (ht[4*tw*((Y)%th)+4*((X)%tw)+0])
#define RAD(A)  (M_PI*((double)(A))/180.0)
uint8_t *houghtransform(uint8_t *d, int *w, int *h, int *s, int bpp)
{
  int rho, theta, y, x, W = *w, H = *h;
  int th = sqrt(W*W + H*H)/2.0;
  int tw = 360;
  uint8_t *ht = malloc(th*tw*4);
  memset(ht, 0, 4*th*tw); // black bg

  for(rho = 0; rho < th; rho++)
  {
    for(theta = 0; theta < tw/*720*/; theta++)
    {
      double C = cos(RAD(theta));
      double S = sin(RAD(theta));
      uint32_t totalred = 0;
      uint32_t totalgreen = 0;
      uint32_t totalblue = 0;
      uint32_t totalpix = 0;
      if ( theta < 45 || (theta > 135 && theta < 225) || theta > 315) {
    for(y = 0; y < H; y++) {
      double dx = W/2.0 + (rho - (H/2.0-y)*S)/C;
      if ( dx < 0 || dx >= W ) continue;
      x = floor(dx+.5);
      if (x == W) continue;
      totalpix++;
      totalred += GR(x, y);
      totalgreen += GG(x, y);
      totalblue += GB(x, y);
    }
      } else {
    for(x = 0; x < W; x++) {
      double dy = H/2.0 - (rho - (x - W/2.0)*C)/S;
      if ( dy < 0 || dy >= H ) continue;
      y = floor(dy+.5);
      if (y == H) continue;
      totalpix++;
      totalred += GR(x, y);
      totalgreen += GG(x, y);
      totalblue += GB(x, y);      
    }
      }
      if ( totalpix > 0 ) {
    double dp = totalpix;
    SR(theta, rho) = (int)(totalred/dp)   &0xff;
    SG(theta, rho) = (int)(totalgreen/dp) &0xff;
    SB(theta, rho) = (int)(totalblue/dp)  &0xff;
      }
    }
  }

  *h = th;   // sqrt(W*W+H*H)/2
  *w = tw;   // 360
  *s = 4*tw;
  return ht;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cairo_surface_t *inputimg = NULL;
  cairo_surface_t *houghimg = NULL;

  uint8_t *houghdata = NULL, *inputdata = NULL;
  int w, h, s, bpp;

  if ( argc < 3 ) return EXIT_FAILURE;

  inputimg = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png(argv[1]);

  w = cairo_image_surface_get_width(inputimg);
  h = cairo_image_surface_get_height(inputimg);
  s = cairo_image_surface_get_stride(inputimg);  
  bpp = cairo_image_surface_get_format(inputimg);
  switch(bpp)
  {
  case CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32: bpp = 4; break;
  case CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24:  bpp = 3; break;
  case CAIRO_FORMAT_A8:     bpp = 1; break;
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "unsupported\n");
    goto destroy;
  }

  inputdata = cairo_image_surface_get_data(inputimg);
  houghdata = houghtransform(inputdata, &w, &h, &s, bpp);

  printf("w=%d, h=%d\n", w, h);
  houghimg = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(houghdata,
                         CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,
                         w, h, s);
  cairo_surface_write_to_png(houghimg, argv[2]);

destroy:
  if (inputimg != NULL) cairo_surface_destroy(inputimg);
  if (houghimg != NULL) cairo_surface_destroy(houghimg);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the whole listing is typeset with the same left margins as the rest of the text. To get what you want it has to be broken outside the TeX page breaking algorithm, and then be typeset shifted to the left (into the marginpar area) on even pages before being put on the page. This can be achieved with the `framed` package, by putting the briken pieces in a kind of virtual "frame", that positions it properly on the page, i.e. sticking out to the right on an odd page, and sticking out to the left on an even page.

Here is a solution, defining a `widelst` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[includeall]{geometry}
\usepackage{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\lstlen
\setlength{\lstlen}{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}

\usepackage{framed}
\newenvironment{widelst}
  {\def\FrameCommand##1{%
      \ifodd\value{page}\makebox[\textwidth][l]{##1}\else\makebox[\textwidth][r]{##1}\fi}%
    \MakeFramed{\FrameRestore}}
  {\endMakeFramed}

\lstset{%
    basicstyle          = \ttfamily\small,
    language            = c,
    columns             = fullflexible,
    flexiblecolumns     = false,
    emptylines          = *1,
    tabsize             = 4,
    breaklines          = true,
    showstringspaces    = false,
    linewidth           = \lstlen,
    frame               = single,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]
\begin{widelst}
    \begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cairo.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.1415927
#endif

#define GR(X,Y) (d[(*s)*(Y)+bpp*(X)+((2)%bpp)])
#define GG(X,Y) (d[(*s)*(Y)+bpp*(X)+((1)%bpp)])
#define GB(X,Y) (d[(*s)*(Y)+bpp*(X)+((0)%bpp)])
#define SR(X,Y) (ht[4*tw*((Y)%th)+4*((X)%tw)+2])
#define SG(X,Y) (ht[4*tw*((Y)%th)+4*((X)%tw)+1])
#define SB(X,Y) (ht[4*tw*((Y)%th)+4*((X)%tw)+0])
#define RAD(A)  (M_PI*((double)(A))/180.0)
uint8_t *houghtransform(uint8_t *d, int *w, int *h, int *s, int bpp)
{
  int rho, theta, y, x, W = *w, H = *h;
  int th = sqrt(W*W + H*H)/2.0;
  int tw = 360;
  uint8_t *ht = malloc(th*tw*4);
  memset(ht, 0, 4*th*tw); // black bg

  for(rho = 0; rho < th; rho++)
  {
    for(theta = 0; theta < tw/*720*/; theta++)
    {
      double C = cos(RAD(theta));
      double S = sin(RAD(theta));
      uint32_t totalred = 0;
      uint32_t totalgreen = 0;
      uint32_t totalblue = 0;
      uint32_t totalpix = 0;
      if ( theta < 45 || (theta > 135 && theta < 225) || theta > 315) {
    for(y = 0; y < H; y++) {
      double dx = W/2.0 + (rho - (H/2.0-y)*S)/C;
      if ( dx < 0 || dx >= W ) continue;
      x = floor(dx+.5);
      if (x == W) continue;
      totalpix++;
      totalred += GR(x, y);
      totalgreen += GG(x, y);
      totalblue += GB(x, y);
    }
      } else {
    for(x = 0; x < W; x++) {
      double dy = H/2.0 - (rho - (x - W/2.0)*C)/S;
      if ( dy < 0 || dy >= H ) continue;
      y = floor(dy+.5);
      if (y == H) continue;
      totalpix++;
      totalred += GR(x, y);
      totalgreen += GG(x, y);
      totalblue += GB(x, y);      
    }
      }
      if ( totalpix > 0 ) {
    double dp = totalpix;
    SR(theta, rho) = (int)(totalred/dp)   &0xff;
    SG(theta, rho) = (int)(totalgreen/dp) &0xff;
    SB(theta, rho) = (int)(totalblue/dp)  &0xff;
      }
    }
  }

  *h = th;   // sqrt(W*W+H*H)/2
  *w = tw;   // 360
  *s = 4*tw;
  return ht;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cairo_surface_t *inputimg = NULL;
  cairo_surface_t *houghimg = NULL;

  uint8_t *houghdata = NULL, *inputdata = NULL;
  int w, h, s, bpp;

  if ( argc < 3 ) return EXIT_FAILURE;

  inputimg = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png(argv[1]);

  w = cairo_image_surface_get_width(inputimg);
  h = cairo_image_surface_get_height(inputimg);
  s = cairo_image_surface_get_stride(inputimg);  
  bpp = cairo_image_surface_get_format(inputimg);
  switch(bpp)
  {
  case CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32: bpp = 4; break;
  case CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24:  bpp = 3; break;
  case CAIRO_FORMAT_A8:     bpp = 1; break;
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "unsupported\n");
    goto destroy;
  }

  inputdata = cairo_image_surface_get_data(inputimg);
  houghdata = houghtransform(inputdata, &w, &h, &s, bpp);

  printf("w=%d, h=%d\n", w, h);
  houghimg = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(houghdata,
                         CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,
                         w, h, s);
  cairo_surface_write_to_png(houghimg, argv[2]);

destroy:
  if (inputimg != NULL) cairo_surface_destroy(inputimg);
  if (houghimg != NULL) cairo_surface_destroy(houghimg);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{widelst}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Trying to add `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\begin{widelst}\singlespacing}` and `\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\end{widelst}}`, but it failed. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: For me it works. But did you include `\usepackage{setspace}` and 
`\usepackage{etoolbox}`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot to include `setspace`. Thank you very much.